# Node backend execute function after three days

Tags: node.js, web, backend

I'm developing a web app with the MEVN stack and aws lambda. Users of the site are able to send requests to other users, but I'd like these requests to expire after three days. The function to delete a request is easy enough, but I don't know the best way to run it only after three days.

I don't want to setTimeout for that long, and I don't think Lambda would allow it anyway.

One way I could do it is just check if more than three days have passed the next time either of the two users log-on to the site, but I'd like to send an email when the request expires, and if neither user logs on for a month, the email wouldn't be sent until then.

Thanks so much for any help

Comment: You can trigger lambdas based on cron expressions, so you can have one that runs, say, every hour or every day: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html

Comment: I think batch dealing with cron is good enough, for you are not so strict with time. If truely need to be strict, you need ecs to run your timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would schedule a lambda to run once a day and expire the items that are elapsed three days. if you want it to expire in exactly three days, you could run the lambda every minute